# How to store JSON data in an element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My page is receiving JSON encoded data from a php script. Using my browsers dev network tool I can see the data is as follows:

```
{"state":200,"message":null,"result":"..\/0images\/listimg\/orig\/54ab4719bf848.jpeg","id":"957"}
```

I have an input tag on the page called

```
<input class="avatar-src" name="avatar_src" type="hidden" value="">
```

Using jquery, I would like to store the value for "id" from the json string in the value attribute of my input tag.

There is a JS script that is already processing the "state", "message" and "result" objects from the json string. If possible I would like to leave that script alone and use a separate one to extract the JSON object "id". How would I do this?

Here is part of the first ajax response that manages "state" "message" and "result"

```
 ajaxUpload: function () {
  var url = this.$avatarForm.attr("action"),
      data = new FormData(this.$avatarForm[0]),
      _this = this;

  $.ajax(url, {
    type: "post",
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,

    beforeSend: function () {
      _this.submitStart();
    },

    success: function (data) {
      _this.submitDone(data);
    },

    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      _this.submitFail(textStatus || errorThrown);
    },

    complete: function () {
      _this.submitEnd();
    }
  });
},

syncUpload: function () {
  this.$avatarSave.click();
},

submitStart: function () {

},

submitDone: function (data) {
  console.log(data);

  try {
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
  } catch (e) {};

  if (data && data.state === 200) {
    if (data.result) {
      this.url = data.result;

      if (this.support.datauri || this.uploaded) {
        this.uploaded = false;
        this.cropDone();
      } else {
        this.uploaded = true;
        this.$avatarSrc.val(this.url);
        this.startCropper();
      }

      this.$avatarInput.val("");
    } else if (data.message) {
      this.alert(data.message);
    }
  } else {
    this.alert("Failed to response");
  }
},
```

Comment: You just write the corresponding code after the code that processes `state`, `message` and `result`

Comment: Can you also post the script you're using for your AJAX call (assuming that you're using it, although I can't tell from your question)? You can easy access the ID using the JSON object notation, i.e. `.id`. If your returned data is stored in a variable as `data`, then the ID is simply a matter of reading `data.id`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to start by giving your input tag an ID attribute AS WELL AS a name attribute so it can be uniquely referenced.

So whatever var you populate with the JSON object (let's just call it: var jSn):

```
<input id="avatar_src" name="avatar_src" class="avatar-src" type="hidden" value="">
<script>
 $('#avatar_src').val(jSn.id);
</script>
```

Comment: jquery doesn't have a `value()` method

Comment: @charlietfl it does have val() though

Comment: Edited to val() vs value()

Comment: would it be standard to have an event listener for this? Also, how does that direct it into the value attribute? seems like it would just apply it to the tag

Comment: You're going to need to post the ajax code too.  That's the missing piece here.  Usually when the ajax is called a value is populated with the returned object.  So every time that ajax is called the value would be changed.  Are you saying that every time that value is changed, that you want to automatically update the value of the input field?

Comment: @ZacWolf yes i would want it to automatically populate. and the ajax code has been added to OP question

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle for this?  Your usage of $variable names is confusing, so I'm not sure if you're using someone besides jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is *actually* JSON, you'd have to parse it first...  For instance, say your JSON was linked to a reference (variable):

```
var myJSON = '{"state":200,"message":null,"result":"..\/0images\/listimg\/orig\/54ab4719bf848.jpeg","id":"957"}';
```

From here, you'd have to parse the JSON into a JavaScript object with `JSON.parse`:

```
var myJSON = JSON.parse(myJSON);
```

Then, from here you can select the values as a JavaScript object.

```
$(".avatar-src").val(myJSON.id);
```

Comment: How would I assign var myjson though to whatever string comes in? it's always going to be different values for id

Comment: If you're using Ajax to get a different set up ID's every time.  You simply assign the Ajax response to the variable.  `myJSON = ajaxResponse;`.  Each time the Ajax is `ajaxResponse` will be different, and since variables are references not copies it'd work out fine.  I could edit the question if you post more code regarding your Ajax.